# Prevent right div from dropping below when the left one is expanded

Tags: html, scroll, css-float

I have two divs that I want to have side by side. The left div is expandable with the help of `jquery-ui resizable` function. When I expand the left div after some point the right one drops below. But I would expect the horizontal scroll bar to appear instead. What do I have to do to avoid this? Here's the HTML,CSS and the script that helps to expand the left div.

HTML:

```
<div class="left">
    <h2>Left DIV</h2>
</div>
<div class="right">
        <h2>Right DIV</h2>
</div>
```

CSS:

> div.left {
>       float: left;
>       width: 100px;
>       height: 680px;
>       border-right: 5px solid #e7e8e1;
>       white-space: nowrap;
>       z-index: -1;
>       background-color:green; }
>
> div.right{
>       float: left; 
>       padding-left: 5px; 
>       background: navy;
>       width:300px;
>        }

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div.left').resizable({
       handles: "e", minWidth: 100, maxWidth: 270});}
);
```

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/60won7of/)

Comment: I can't tell what you mean when you refer to expanding the left div and the right one dropping below.  I can't replicate on the fiddle

Comment: Just resize up the left div to its maximum allowed size and you'll see that the right div disappears. In fact it does not disappear, it's below the left div now. When you resize the left div down the right div will come back. Just hover over the right edge of the left div and double headed arrow will come up.